# need to show images from a URL on a list view populated by JSON

Tags: android, android-listview, layout-inflater

I need to show images from a URL on a list view populated by JSON.

This is the main piece of code used to inflate the layout for each JSON object. It is working fine for text and integer values, but I am not able to show any of the images.
Each object has an image defined by its file name, stored as text on a string field, and all of them have a common URL path:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.ofertas_app_custom_list, null);           
        }

        Ofertas_Application app = items.get(position);

        if(app != null) {

            TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView direccionText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView valoracionText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            if(titleText != null) titleText.setText(app.getNombreEmpresa());//populate textView1

            if (direccionText !=null) direccionText.setText(app.getDireccionEmpresa());//populate textView2
            if (valoracionText !=null) valoracionText.setText(String.valueOf(app.getValoracionEmpresa()));


            ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg");

                HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                        .execute(httpRequest);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }  

        }

        return v;
    }
```

Prior to use the parsed objects image names, I am checking the app using a URL, but the list rows always show the default image declared at the layout file, in this case a facebook icon.

I need your help to implement the right way to show the image of the object at every object row.
Thank you

EDITED QUESTION:

This is a screenshot from the listview after implementing the answer by Libin:

[image]

The default picture is the facebook icon.

LIST ITEM LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#5981b2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="30"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/valoracion"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:lines="2"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"

    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:lines="2"
    android:text="Small Text esta eb kac  case deded eadad"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your trying to access the network `URL` from main thread. You need to do the network request on the background thread.

Use `AsyncTask` like this

```
 new AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>(){
            @Override
            protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) {
                try{

                    URL url = new URL("http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg");
                    - - - - - - - -
                    // add your code to fetch the image
                    - - - - - - -
                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
```

**EDIT**

Here is the complete code, on how to make this working on your adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.ofertas_app_custom_list, null);
    }

    Ofertas_Application app = items.get(position);

    if(app != null) {

        TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView direccionText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView valoracionText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        if(titleText != null) titleText.setText(app.getNombreEmpresa());//populate textView1

        if (direccionText !=null) direccionText.setText(app.getDireccionEmpresa());//populate textView2
        if (valoracionText !=null) valoracionText.setText(String.valueOf(app.getValoracionEmpresa()));

        final ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        new AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>(){
            @Override
            protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) {
                try {

                    URL url = new URL("http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg");

                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                    httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                            .execute(httpRequest);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need your help to use your code proposal inside my code. Would you mind telling me what should I remove or replace with your code?

Comment: You need to just add your try-catch codes inside doInBackground()

Comment: i am very sorry, but I am not able to do it as you expect. I am getting lots of errors. You are kindly requested to update your answer   including how should the getView() method be changed to include your proposed piece of code, I don't really know how to do it. Of course, if you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you very much, it doesn't throw any error, but the image is not changed, the default image is shown. I miss there a code line like this one: if (direccionText !=null) direccionText.setText(app.getDireccionEmpresa()); but referred to the imageView1. The method that makes the call for the image name is getImagenEmpresa();

Comment: please see the updated question where I have included a screenshot.

Comment: post your list item layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50656/discussion-between-libin-and-mvasco)

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission in manifest? Use the chat link to respond

Comment: Hi Libin, there is no exception at all, but I will try to explain what is happening with the app. As it is now, included your proposal, the list view is shown as it was before, that means, the facebook icon is shown on each row.If I click on any row, then the first row's facebook icon is changed by the image from the URL. Strange, isn't it???

Answer (score 1):

You can't load the image from the web on the main thread. Place that code in a separate thread. I would recommend usung the universal image loader library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thank you,but I will try to follow the answer by Libin.